# Can we interchange one row and one column in a determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, determinant

Can we swap the ith row and the ith coloumn in a determinant as an elementary operation? What happens when we do interchange them? Does the value of the determinant remain constant or does it change?

Comment: How do we swap row $1$ and column $2$ in $\left[\begin{matrix}1&2\\3&4\end{matrix}\right]$? Seems to me like we run into some definitional problems. Maybe you want to restrict to swapping the $i$-th row and the $i$-th column?

Comment: If one interchanges only one row and column, then the oter columns and rows dont remain t'he same in general, so the value of the determinant is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example as simple as possible:

$\begin{vmatrix}0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 1&0&0\end{vmatrix} = 1$

Now, switching the first row with the first column we would get:

$\begin{vmatrix}0&0&1 \\ 1&0&1 \\ 0&0&0\end{vmatrix} = 0$

**No**, this transformation doesn't preserve the value of the determinant.